# Datatables DOM positioning

Tags: jquery, dom, datatables, position

Is there any more documentation about DOM positioning other than here? https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html

For example, I want to position the entries select field & the entries info under the pagination. How would I achieve this?

This is what I got so far:

```
$("#relations-table").dataTable({
    "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
    columnDefs: [ { "orderable": false, "targets": [0] } ],
    //pageLength: 50
    "dom": '<"top"rf>t<"bottom"pli>'
});

$(".dataTables_length").css({ "margin-top": "-35px" });
```

Comment: It's working for you? https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/41/

Comment: The entries info & dropdown are at the bottom now which is good. But they should be bottom right (below the pagination). Also, the search input is at the bottom right now, which should remain at the top right. The entries text are being shown twice now aswell.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
 dom:
    "<'row'<'col-sm-6'B><'col-sm-6'f>>" +
    "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
    "<'row'<'col-sm-4'i><'col-sm-4 text-center'l><'col-sm-4'p>>",
```